# Additional fields in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, many-to-many

In a user schema, I need to define a field of contacts with a `blocked` property.

My actual definition goes like this:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  // Other fields
  // ...
  contacts: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }]
}

const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

From there I was unable to find a possible way to add the `blocked` field in the same referenced relationship `contacts`. Is it necessary to create an Intermediary Collection to add the additional field to the relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a contact collection which holds at the same time a reference to the user plus the additional fields that I need:

```
//user.js
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  // Other fields
  // ...
  contacts: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Contact'
  }]
}

const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

//contact.js
const ContactSchema = new Schema({
  id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  contact: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  blocked: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  }
}

const ContactModel = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);
```